# Trouble using blending options tool in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, blending

I have a Surface Pro 4 and I got Photoshop CS6 64 bit.

I am having some trouble using it though since the words dont show up with the option in the blending pop up window. If I click on it, the action still takes place but I have no idea which is which and would like to know how to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Does this happen in any panel that opens or only blending?

Comment: Have you tried resetting all your preferences?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Something looks wrong here. Why are you trying to add a Layer Style to an Adjustment Layer?

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop allows undocumented combinations of operations. In your version fortunately some absurd combinations at least seem to be grayed. You see one example just now. It's like you are trying to insert layer style Satin to a Channel Mixer adjustment layer, but PS has hidden many parts of the dialog.

Use this dialog (=blending options and layer styles) only for layers which have image content - bitmap, shapes or text. Layer opacity (it's one of the blending options) is meaningful also for adjustment layers, but you can adjust it in the layers panel for adjustment layers. It affects the depth of the adjustment.

I bet Adobe's engineers haven't figured out what Satin should mean for adjustment layers, but that doesn't prevent older than CS6 legacy Photoshops to show all dialog texts and parameters and create unpredictable results, when one does some adjustments.